# RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory says “type” not defined

Tags: java, android, gson

I am dealing with a situation where I have polymorphic classes that I need to deserialize.

```
Class Pen{
  String name;
  List<Animal> animals;
}

//Animal can be an interface or parent class: I am flexible

Class Animal{
  AnimalType type;//enum
  int legs;
}

enum AnimalType{
  dog,cat,pig,chicken;
}

Class AnimalDog extends Animal{
  //…
}

Class AnimalCat extends Animal{
  //…
}


Class AnimalPig extends Animal{
  //…
}
```

then I create my Gson instance with

```
public static Gson instanceUpperCamelCaseWithTypeAdapterFactory() {
    if (null == sGsonUpperCamelCase) {
        final RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<Animal> typeFactory = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory
                .of(Animal.class, “type")
                .registerSubtype(AnimalDog.class, “dog”)
                .registerSubtype(AnimalCat.class, “cat”)
                .registerSubtype(AnimalPig.class, “pig”);

        sGsonUpperCamelCase = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
                .registerTypeAdapterFactory(typeFactory).create();
    }//the naming policy is because server sends me upper case fields whereas Java fields are lowercase.
    return sGsonUpperCamelCase;
}
```

To get the animals from a json that contains a list of animals, I do

```
List<Animal> animals = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Animal>>() {}.getType());
```

I am completely a newbie to Gson. Completely. So without confusing me too much, how might I solve this problem?

Error trace:

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: cannot deserialize class com.company.appname.data.model.Animal because it does not define a field named type
com.company.appname.utils.RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java:204)
com.google.gson.TypeAdapter$1.read(TypeAdapter.java:199)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:217)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:861)
com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:826)
com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
```

I run the json through an online validator, there is no problem with it. It has a number of items. Here I show two.

```
{“Animals”:[{  
           “id":9,
           “type”:”dog”,
           “name”:”maximus”
        },
        {  
           “id":10,
           “type”:”cat”,
           “name”:”meowy”,
           “yarns”:5,
           “nice”:true
        }]}
```

Comment: It seems there is a silly person tracking me to give me -1 for every question.  Thanks to whoever up-voted to counter that silly person. And thanks for any help I get solving this problem.

Comment: try chaining `type` to `String` and provide the label to the super class

Comment: @Blackbelt I don't understand the comment. "chaining type to String"?

Comment: change `AnimalType type;` to `String type;`, and assign "dog" to it from `AnimalDog` (do the same for the other animals)

Comment: Ah I find the bug, but not the solution (+1). Once Gson uses the "type" field to find the appropriate subclass, it sets the actual type field to null. But in my case I use the field to do more work. Is there a way to keep Gson from swallowing up the value of the `type` field?

Comment: did you try to initialize it from the children ?

Comment: ??? You have all my code. I get json from server. to get type I do `animal.getType()` and the value is null. And that's after changing `type` to String instead of using enum.

Comment: could you post the json?

Comment: `type` is a `String`. How should it be parsed in a Enum? Could you try changing the enum like: `enum AnimalType{
  @SerializedName("dog") 
 dog,
  @SerializedName("cat")
 cat,
 @SerializedName("pig")
pig,
 @SerializedName("chicken")
chicken;
}`

Comment: I stopped using enum altogether and use String. The `type` value still gets swallowed. In fact, if I remove the type field from the POJO it still works as long as the json from the server has the type field. So the field is thought to be for the `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` and not for the object and so it is not serialized as part of the POJO.

Answer (score 5):

RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.class 
line number -> 203

**need replace**

```
JsonElement labelJsonElement = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().remove(typeFieldName);
```

**with**

```
JsonElement labelJsonElement = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get(typeFieldName);
```

Answer (score -1):

i've found bug in RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory (line 185, method create(), and resolved this issue, need replace

```
if (type.getRawType() != baseType)
```

with

```
if (null == type || !baseType.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType()))
```

Then RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory works well as expected.

See link [registered issue with suggested fix](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/712#issuecomment-183432959)

Comment: This isn't a proper solution, nor does it fix the issue.

Comment: Could you add more details, what exactly wrong? This solution is checked for some years.